# count items in list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list (ll) of lists (l1,l2,l3) that have the same length.

```
l1 <- list( c("a","b","c") , c("d","e","f") , c(NULL) )
l2 <- list( c("a","b") , c("d","e") , c(NULL) )
l3 <- list( c("a") , c("d") , c("g") ) 
ll <- list(l1,l2,l3)
str(ll)
List of 3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "d" "e" "f"
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "d" "e"
  ..$ : NULL
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ : chr "d"
  ..$ : chr "g"
```

is there a way to create a (summary?) table that counts/compares how many items are in each list, whitout using for/loop?

i'm thinking of an output like this:

```
list 1 2 3
l1 3 3 0
l2 2 2 0
l3 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try:

```
t(sapply(ll, function(x) lapply(x,length)))

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 3    3    0   
#[2,] 2    2    0   
#[3,] 1    1    1
```

Edit:

as pointed out by @Ryan in the comments, the following simplifies it:

```
t(sapply(ll, lengths))
```

Comment: or `t(sapply(ll, lengths))`. Using `lapply`, the elements of the matrix are lists, not integers or doubles.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `lengths` with `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(ll, lengths))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    3    0
#[2,]    2    2    0
#[3,]    1    1    1
```

---

Or with `lengths` on `simplify2array`

```
lengths(simplify2array(ll))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    2    1
#[2,]    3    2    1
#[3,]    0    0    1
```

Taking the transpose gets the expected output

Comment: I report getting the same output as @akrun. R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

Comment: I have updated my R and it solved the issue I've had. Solution 2 works fine. Yet the DOC still states: "Get the length of each element of a list or atomic vector (is.atomic) as an integer or numeric **vector**. I would not call a matrix a vector ... my bad for not having the latest version. But no bad intention on my side, akrun.

Comment: @AndreElrico  No problem. It could be a change in the version behavior

Answer (score 3):

Another option. `rapply` counts the number of elements in the lists within the list. If you are fine with having these counts in a list, you could go with `ll2` as your final result. The `stri_list2matrix` function can be used to convert the data into a matrix. We specify that empty lists get a value zero.

```
ll2 <- rapply(ll, length, how="list")
ll2

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[3]]
list()


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[3]]
list()


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 1

library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(lapply(ll2, unlist), byrow=TRUE, fill=0)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "3"  "3"  "0" 
[2,] "2"  "2"  "0" 
[3,] "1"  "1"  "1"
```

Comment: I knew `rapply` would show up somewhere on this post

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ll <- list(l1 = l1,l2 = l2,l3 = l3)
as.data.frame(sapply(ll, function(x){sapply(x, length)}, USE.NAMES = T))

#   l1 l2 l3
# 1  3  2  1
# 2  3  2  1
# 3  0  0  1
```